# Passing a reference through multiple methods, what aproach is better

Tags: java

I have a HashMap that i need to send to 2 methos, each method might add entries to it, I return the HashMap afterwards. What is the more clean approach to this:

```
  public HashMap<String, Boolean> getDataMap() {
    HashMap<String, Boolean> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

    gatherData1(resultMap);
    gatherData2(resultMap);
    
    return resultMap;
}
```

or

```
public HashMap<String, Boolean> getDataMap() {
    HashMap<String, Boolean> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

    resultMap = gatherData1(resultMap);
    resultMap = gatherData2(resultMap);
    
    return resultMap;
}
```

What approach is cleaner, in the second example it is more obvious that the 2 methods are there for operating on the input and returning a result so it is more readable but also maybe its not so usefull or even confusing for some. Im just interested in a proper way of doing things especially since this can get a lot more complex and as a result a lot harder to read and understand by other people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a major difference between the two snippets. The second one can return a *new* `Map`, that may or may not contain the data that was originally in the `resultMap`.
The first one can only mutate the input parameter, and it is a topic open for discussion wether or not methods are allowed to modify the input. Imho they should not, they should operate on the input and return output, end of story.

Therefore I would recommend / prefer the second snippet including modifying the `gatherData` implementation to not mutate the passed map but instead return a new one. You may even not pass `resultMap` in at all but instead just return a completely new map and make the merging / combining of the `resultMap` and the the return value of `gatherData` part of the `getDataMap` implementation. That should be the implementation if `gatherData` does not actually need the `Map` for some internal logic.

If this is just for config purposes and the `gatherData` methods are very simple, do not have a lot of logic or not much else happens to the `resultMap` then it *may* be fine to modify the input parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If the method does not copy the map, but only adds entries (or removes or updates entries), then there is simply no need to return the map, as the reference to the map is the same across the caller and callee methods. It's not a matter of readability but more of avoiding redundant reassignment. If the method otherwise creates a new copy, then you'd have the return new map.

Comment: But the map is created within the "getDataMap()" method in both examples, surely the map then has to be returned in both cases, no matter the actions taken on said map?

Comment: @Hellothisisme I'm referring to the methods `gatherData1` and `gatherData2`.